# SQL Server bind parameters

Tags: sql-server, bind

I have some code which I can't find the problem in, I can't bind parameters:

```
$id =1;
$pass =0x3A;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT [UID]
      ,[ID]
      ,[PWD]
  FROM [kal_auth].[dbo].[Login] WHERE [ID] =? AND [PWD]=?");
$stmt->execute(array($id,$pass));
$stmt->fetchAll();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

this code found COUNT 0

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT [UID]
      ,[ID]
      ,[PWD]
  FROM [kal_auth].[dbo].[Login] WHERE [ID] =1 AND [PWD]=0x3A");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchAll();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

and this code work and find 1 row.

I have also tried `PDOStatement::bindParam` and `PDOStatement::bindValue` they don't work both, I really can't find where my mistake is ....

My query worked in SQL Server as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you pass your parameters in the first query as expected?

Comment: yes i have pass them

Comment: this code worked with mysql as well